# Google Cloud Function costs

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-functions, cost-management, google-cloud-billing

I am trying to check how much do we pay for each Cloud Function per month. When I access the billing page in Google Cloud Console, I am able to filter only for all Cloud Functions, but I can't choose a specific function. Is there a way to check how much did function XYZ cost for last month?

I've read through this https://cloud.google.com/functions/pricing#cloud_functions_pricing, but it doesn't mention how to do what I need to do.

Comment: I always enable billing data export to BigQuery. You can query on just about anything using SQL. I do not remember if the export contains details per Cloud Function but I think it does. There are a number of open-source tools and dashboards to help you analyze billing data in BigQuery.

Comment: I can't see it there. I am using the pricing export (https://cloud.google.com/billing/docs/how-to/export-data-bigquery#setup). Also I am bit worried that Google doesn't offer this at all (if they did, why wouldn't they add it to the default dashboard in GCP?)

Comment: Did you just enable export? If yes, you will need to wait for a billing cycle. Stackoverflow cannot change what Google Cloud exports. I recommend contacting Google Cloud Billing Support (which is free). https://cloud.google.com/support/billing

Comment: Hi John, we've enabled this a few weeks ago, so we already have the data. Nevertheless, there is nothing that would help me identify costs of a specific function.

Comment: Thank you for the feedback. Billing is an area that I try to stay up to date on. I will look into this and update my videolabs on Google Cloud Billing once I learn more: https://www.jhanley.com/videolabs/Google-Cloud-Billing/ In the meantime if billing support provides new information let me know.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it is not about programming.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To view the cost per function, you need to export the billing to BigQuery (as mentioned by John in the comment), **AND** to [add labels on functions](https://cloud.google.com/resource-manager/docs/creating-managing-labels). Then you will be able to select the cost per label in BigQuery and like this you will be able to view the cost per function.

But only for the future, you can't have this for the past costs.

Comment: Thanks! I was thinking about creating a service account for each function as the last resort solution, but this is obviously much better.

Comment: Your answer explains why I thought that this detail was available in billing exports. I usually add labels and that I forgot about that item being the magic key.